# How can my Azure Logic App authenticate via AD to call my .Net endpoint?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps

I have an ASP.NET CORE razor pages application that also has some API controllers that I can call with javascript. I am further building these controllers out to soon fully convert to a Web API. Now, I have a need for an Azure Logic App to call one of these controller's endpoints but the application uses Microsoft's AD identity platform. This is all out of the box, so when my javascript calls these endpoints it's already authenticated.

[Reading Microsoft's own documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-custom-api-authentication), I opted to use their "no code" solution which adds Microsoft as an IP through the azure portal for the application.

Current set-up (This currently works for the app):

- My application is registered in Azure as an App Registration
- This app registration has my redirect URIs defined
- The code of my application passes that application ID, secret,
  tenant, etc to the AD auth call
- The Azure App Service does not have an identity platform attached
- *Note that Microsoft assumes your app is an App Service, mine is not it is an App Registration

Attempt (Following the documentation):

- I created an App Registration for my Logic App
- I add Microsoft IP authentication to my App Service
- I add the Logic App's client id, secret, tenant, and the App Service's client id to it's call

  ```
  "authentication": {
     "tenant": "Tenant ID",
     "audience": "App Service client ID",
     "clientId": "Logic App client ID",
     "secret": "Logic App secret",
     "type": "ActiveDirectoryOAuth"
  }
  ```

Routing anywhere in my existing dev environment gives the following error:

```
Message: AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application
```

And my Logic App receives a 302 redirect status code which tries to redirect to the Microsoft login page.

I believe this is adding another layer of authentication on-top of what my code is already adding with the out-of-the-box .NET AD authentication. Ultimately I would like my pages to be protected with the built in AD authentication, my controllers to be accessible by those pages with the existing auth, and my logic app to be able to authenticate to access those controllers. **If adding Microsoft's IP on the App Service is not necessary, what can my logic app provide (Audience field) to authenticate?**

Edit:
[Found more Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-multiple-authentication-schemes) that shows how to add multiple authentication schemes to the .Net project. My current app uses OpenId in `Startup.cs` like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

This uses a cookie that allows my web app to prompt the user to sign-in if they aren't authenticated. The 302s I am getting is exactly that. If I follow that documentation, and JwtBearer as a second/additional authentication scheme I can now have both the web app re-direct to Microsoft to sign-in, and make a postman call using an existing access token:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

I would still like to find any solution to avoid code changes and maintain the existing OpenId authentication scheme though.

Comment: This is a server to server authentication so you need to use the client credentials flow. Also you could use a managed identity rather than an app registration

Comment: @Thomas Changing authentication in the Logic App to Managed Identity and giving it the client ID of the web app as the audience still returns a 302 redirect as the response

Comment: Could you share your logic app flow please ?

Comment: @Thomas Currently it's a single Http action just to test hitting my endpoint. [This was the initial attempt that gives a 302 redirect](https://imgur.com/a/OUn6cEw). If I use an incorrect value for audience, client id, etc it will give me a meaningful error. If I use all the correct values, or if I switch the authentication on the Http action to managed identity, I get a 302.

Comment: so if you try to get a token using the client_id/client_secret (postman) used by the logic app, do you receive a valid token ?

Comment: @Thomas Editing my post with some more info. I can get a token from login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT ID>/oauth2/token but using it still gives a 302 on external calls to the api. My .net project is using OpenId authentication with `.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp` in startup.cs. The web app relies on a cookie and does not have JwtBearer setup. If I add JwtBearer to the authentication I can now use the token. My hope though is not having to modify my code like that and instead  provide something from the Logic App to still authenticate

Comment: make sense, you do need to enable jwt bearer auth as the logic app call is server to server auth so no browser = no cookie

Comment: so you re web app is access by users from browser and also the logic app ? you can setup different auth type of different controller as well i guess

Comment: @Thomas thank you, yes it started as an asp net core web app, is slowly being transitioned to a web api so we can move to a different front end, and logic app needs to call the api. So for now it needs client side and server to server